# Jquery Dropdown Date Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using the jQuery Validation plugin to validate a signup form for my site.  One of the required things a user must do is enter their birthday, they have to be 18 to use the site.  I am having the birthday entered through three dropdown menus.  I want to validate this entry (to make sure they did it and to make sure they are at least 18, but I am failing to understand the building of custom validators.  Here is my code in the form:

```
<p>
            <label for="user_birthday">Birthday</label>
            <br>
            <select id="user_birthday_2i" name="user[birthday(2i)]">
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            etc....
            </select>
            <select id="user_birthday_3i" name="user[birthday(3i)]">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            etc...
            </select>
            <select id="user_birthday_1i" name="user[birthday(1i)]">
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            etc...
            </select>
          </p>
```

Anyone ever built a validator like this before using the jQuery Validation plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), and it was working well, so I wanted to stick with it.  Basically I had to add a custom validator, and ended up using the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library to interpret the date.  Like so:

```
# formats the date into a hidden field that can be validated when the dropdowns are changed.
$('#user_birthday_3i,#user_birthday_2i,#user_birthday_1i').change(function() {  
      $('#user_birthday').val($('#user_birthday_3i').val()+'/'+ $('#user_birthday_2i').val()+'/'+ $('#user_birthday_1i').val());
    });


# uses date.js to interpret the date and do a little math
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ofAge", function(value, element) { 
        return Date.parse($("#user_birthday").val()) < (18).years().ago();
    }, "You must be 18 years old to join.");


# validated the form using the jquery validation plugin
$("#new_user_signup").validate({
    rules: {
        "user[birthday]": {
            required: true,
            date: true,
            ofAge: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "user[birthday]": {
            required: "Please enter your birthday.",
            date: "Please enter your birthday."
        }
    }
});
```

Not sure if it was the best method, overall, but it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

People usually know their birthday pretty well, so I'd rather let them type it in. Validating a date is pretty easy too.

```
Birthday:<input name="birthday" onblur="validate18(this);">
<br>
<span class="hint">day/month/year</span>
<br>
<span id="birthdayError" class="errorMessage"></span>

<script>

function validate18(el) {
    var bits = typeof el.value == 'string'? el.value.split('/') : [];
    var d = new Date(bits[2], bits[1]-1, bits[0]);
    var err = document.getElementById(el.name + 'Error');

    // Check date was valid
    if (d && d.getFullYear() == bits[2] && d.getMonth() == bits[1]-1) {

        // Check is 18 years ago or more
        var testDate = new Date();
        var testDate = testDate.setYear(testDate.getFullYear() - 18);
        err.innerHTML = (testDate - d < 0)? 'Sorry, you aren\'t 18 yet' : '';
    } else {
      err.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid date';
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is good.  Is there any particular reason you go for input over dropdowns? I just don't want to run into an issue where a user is entering 3-3-85 instead of 3/3/85, or people from different countries, etc.  Seems like it's more work for the user.

Comment: You can use a regular expression in the split to split on anything you like, even /\D/ so any non-digit character. I prefer to type it in as date pickers are annoying, just do what's best for your users.